# Can `mysqlcheck` help me resolve database problems without damaging my database?

Tags: mysql, database

**Background**

I have a Drupal site with a database that is managed with phpmyadmin. The database is over 1500 tables in size. I'm having huge issues with speed and was looking for a good fix. The database is 2.5-3 years old and has never been maintained (to the best of my knowledge).

**Research**

I've been trying to find a way to speed things up and everything leads me back to the pure size of the database. I came across the command

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE
tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
```

Witch soon lead me to the more powerful

```
mysqlcheck -o <db_schema_name>
```

I don't have a test area to use this command on as we only have one database. I know running this command will take a very long time on my database it could take days because of the sheer size of the database.

**Reasoning**

The reason I would like to use this is because it seems that MySQL shuts down or crashes every day or so. On phpmyadmin I see this

[image: phpmyadmin sql time up]

It has only been up for 9hrs and I haven't switched it off since I started work on this 1 month ago. It seems to never get upto more than 15hrs.

**Status Variables**

This is the list of status variables that are showing values as alerts, I'm hoping to fix some of these with the mysqlcheck.

[image: alert values]

**Conclution**

I would like to know if running mysqlcheck on the database will cause any problems or damage any data in my database. It would also be handy to get an idea of how much time an operation like this will take.

Comment: Have you verified it is not OOMing?

Comment: Also number of failed login attempts is amazing, you sure someone isnt trying to brute force their way in?

Comment: sorry what does the term "OOMing" refer too? because all I'm thinking is healers in world of warcraft shouting "I'm OOM, I'm OOM, don't pull!!!"

Comment: You can better post this one at the DBA stackoverflow forum.

Comment: When the server runs out of memory, the kernel will kill the largest process. Mysql does not just restart on its own. What does the error logs say? Have you done the most basic trouble shooting? Is there anything in the os logs, db logs? Is there enough memory. Is the machine rebooting..... etc etc.

Comment: yeah thats exactly what its doing, nearly everyday I log to the server there are error messages saying apache2 killed some process. thats what is resetting the MySQL? will mysqlcheck have a chance to fix this memory consumption?

Comment: apache2 is the webserver not the kernel. You need to look in syslog and see if mysql is being killed. Your problem is not corrupt tables... What do the mysql error logs say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the answer is the good news... that `mysqlcheck -o` is no more likely to harm your database than is running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on every table, because *that's all it does.*  It's a convenience utility that logs into the server, fetches a list of the tables, and iterates through them, sending an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` query to the server for one table at a time, until it's done.

Now, some bad news.  If you have latent corruption in your tablespaces, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` might run into it, so you should be certain you are prepared for that possibility, with backups and a recovery plan.  The chances of this are fairly remote, but it *is* one possible outcome.

Worse news: are almost certainly barking up the wrong tree.

Running Apache and MySQL together on the same machine with significant traffic -- or significant traffic variation -- is against best practices and is a recipe for problems, because both services tend to increase their memory consumption under load, and if the database is the backing store for web site data, then increased load tends to occur on both services at the same time.

See my answer to [InnoDB Crash Post Mortem on Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem) and [Why is Apache Running Wild and Killing MySQL on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/562453/why-is-apache-running-wild-and-killing-mysql) for thorough coverage of this fairly common problem, where MySQL is the victim, more than anything.

Note that it doesn't matter whether you are using InnoDB or not.  The database recovery entries in the MySQL error log will be a little different, but the dead giveaway is this: preceded by nothing suspicious at all, the MySQL error log says:

```
mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
```

The messages following that one are often misinterpreted as MySQL "crashing," but that's not what's happening... It's been killed.   MySQL may even refuse to restart, until Apache calms down or is restarted, or the server is rebooted.  Again, from the error log, you may or may not additionally see something like this:

```
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
InnoDB: mmap(4395630592 bytes) failed; errno 12
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Checking `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages` (depending on which distro you run) will show you the real issue.

```
$ sudo egrep 'kernel|oom' /var/log/syslog
```

...or messages... should reveal a number of entries beginning something like this:

```
kernel: pcscd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0xd0, order=0, oomkilladj=0
```

Apache gets so memory hungry that the system is at risk of overall instability, so "something" gets sacrificed.  That "something" is likely to be the MySQL Server daemon, `mysqld`.

```
kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 3044, UID 27, (mysqld)
```

MySQL will usually try to restart on its own, and for all you know, this may occasionally be happening, too... but unless Apache's memory demands drop off quickly, MySQL will not be allowed to request sufficient memory from the system, and will give up.

Optimizing the tables has its valid applications... but, in this case, if I have identified your issue correctly, it would be very much comparable to rearranging the deck chairs on the sinking ship *Titanic.*  It may save you some disk space, but it will also cost you some spare disk space while running since some storage engines make an entirely new copy of the table, then rename the copy and delete the old table.  In any event, it's unlikely to have any meaningful impact on memory consumption.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, Thanks again Michael. you've given me some new leads to pursue and way more incite into my database. Great detailed answer.