# Mysql shutsdown in Centos

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have installed Centos on Amazon EC2 .On Centos i installed apache and mysql too . The Mysql server goes down by giving this message

```
 160128 17:26:45 [Warning] IP address 'xx.xx.xx.xx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
 160129 02:29:52 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
 160129 02:29:52 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
 160129  2:30:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 20398 ...
 160129  2:30:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 160129  2:30:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 160129  2:30:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 160129  2:30:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
 160129  2:30:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 160129  2:30:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
 160129  2:30:10 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 160129  2:30:10 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
 160129  2:30:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 160129  2:30:10 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 160129  2:30:10 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 160129  2:30:10 [ERROR] Aborting

 160129  2:30:10 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete

 160129 02:30:10 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Can anyone tell me whats the exact issue . Thanks

Comment: how much memory in your instance? it seems mysql tried to allocate 128Mb for the innodb buffer pool, but couldn't

Comment: thanks for the reply , i am using C4.Large instance and it has 8gb of memory . Is there a way that i can increase the memory for mysql and is it ok that mysql taking that much memory ?

Comment: Note that the `[Warning] IP address...` message is unrelated to the actual trouble, which is that something else on your server is demanding so much memory that the system is looking for a process to kill, and that process happens to be mysql.

Comment: See my answer to [InnoDB Crash Post Mortem on Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem) and [Why is Apache Running Wild and Killing MySQL on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/562453/why-is-apache-running-wild-and-killing-mysql).  It might be arguable that this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189020/can-mysqlcheck-help-me-resolve-database-problems-without-damaging-my-database/31196872#31196872 -- the question is different but the answer is the same.