# error establishing a database connection wordpress in ubuntu server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache2, ubuntu-server

I am using an word press setup in aws ec2 server, while i am working on it suddenly error establish a database connection and i were rebooted the server it works fine after some time it was down again and error log looks like below, Please help me to find the issue

```
(12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
(12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
(12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
(12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`
```

Comment: The fact that you can't establish a database connection seems like a symptom of the problem, not the problem itself.  Fundamentally, you are out of memory, a condition [commonly reported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31196872/1695906) when Apache and MySQL run together on a machine, often assumed to be a database problem but in fact related to Apache configuration.  Hopefully we can get an apache-oriented answer here.