# Scaling from one EC2 instance to two when your application and database are on the same instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, scaling, horizontal-scaling

If I have one EC2 instance that hosts my web application and my MariaDB database, and I want to scale out at some point by separating the web application and database into separate instances, what is the standard practice for doing so without incurring *any* downtime? It seems like a complicated problem to me, but all the posts I've seen discussing the benefits of keeping the web and data tier separate from the get-go mostly talk about security benefits and don't seem to emphasize the scalability benefits which makes me think that it's not as complex a problem as it seems.

Also, in this same scenario, if scaling up and keeping the application and database coupled would be less complex, how would it work? -- keeping in mind the 0 downtime requirement.

Comment: Scaling up a single machine without downtime would mean adding CPU and RAM without a reboot. Not sure if that is possible on EC2. If you already have a load-balancer in place, you prepare the beefier machine in parallel and fallover when it is ready. But you'd need to have all the current data on the new machine, too. So I guess you need at least some read-only mode for a while to copy the data.

Comment: @Thilo how can i guarantee that at the moment i redirect traffic to the new instance that its data will be up to date with the original data?

Comment: So I guess you need at least some read-only mode for a while to copy the data.

Comment: @Thilo yes, but as the copying is going on new data is being added to the original instance -- this is an active social networking application -- so how do i know that a critical piece of information still hasn't been copied to the slave when i finally redirect traffic to the new instance?

Comment: So I guess you need at least some read-only mode for a while to copy the data. In read-only mode, no new data will be added. If that is not acceptable you have to keep some transaction logs and re-apply them immediately after the fallover. This clearly shows the limitation of "scaling up". If you have  multiple machines you don't only get more power, you also get redundancy for cases like this (rolling upgrades).

Answer (score 0):

Familiarize yourself with the way replication works in MariaDB and the solution becomes intuitively obvious.

You create a replica database server by copying the existing database to a new server using `mysqldump` with particular attention to the options `--master-data` and `--single-transaction` to make a backup.  Loading the results onto your new database server creates a replica of the original database *as it existed at the moment you started making the backup*.  InnoDB MVCC assures that the version of each row in each table, as it existed at the beginning of the backup, is what appears on the new server as a result of loading this backup.  (Yes, you have to be using InnoDB, as you should be doing anyway.)

You then connect the new database (as a slave) to the old database (as master), directing it to begin replicating from that same point in time -- the point in time identified by the master log coordinates contained in the backup -- the time the backup was started.

You wait for the slave to be in sync with the master.

Monitoring the replication status using `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` on the master and `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` on the slave, it is trivial to determine when the slave is indeed "current" with the master.  MariaDB replication is "asynchronous" in the sense that changes on the master are made before changes on the slave, but with a slave server of appropriate capacity, the typical replication lag is on the order or milliseconds... and, again, is easily determined.  In the time it takes to stop/start your application, any lingering data can be confirmed to have finished replicating across.

Make the slave writable (typically a slave is set to read-only mode, with the only source of changes being the replication SQL thread, which can of course still write to it) ... then monitor replication to verify sync, stop app, point app to new database, verify replication still in sync, start app... done.  Now, disconnect the slave from the master database and abandon the old master.

Of course, truly zero downtime is effectively impossible, since at some point the application must be reconfigured to connect to a different database... but the total downtime is essentially determined by how fast you can type, or automate the necessary steps to poll both database servers and compare replication coordinates, and make the transition.

At the risk of stating the obvious, never put anything other than the database on the database server, and never collocate it with the application.  No exceptions in production should even be open to discussion.  A problem that comes up all too often, as seen [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25083/11651),  [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25171/11651), [here](https://serverfault.com/a/560554/153161), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196872/1695906) is more often than not attributable to people disregarding this principle, running the application and its database on the same server.  Performance and stability are not only at risk, but the symptoms that arise also give the (incorrect) impression that MySQL (or MariaDB or Percona Server) is at fault, "crashing," when in fact the application is at fault, prompting the OS to force-crash the database in an effort to try to preserve overall machine stability in the face of inevitable memory exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

Put a Load Balancer in front of your EC2 instance, intially just directing traffic to the single instance you have.

Spin up a second instance that will run a copy of your website, get it all configurely and pointing at the DB on the first instance and then add it into the load-balancer so it starts to get traffic

Optional: Add a third instance configured the same as the second, also running a copy of the website only.

Take the original instance out of the LB pool so that web traffic now only goes to #2 and #3.

Deinstall the website from the #1 instance, so it is left only running the db server.