# Linux Mysql server crashes

Tags: mysql, linux, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have just set up an Amazon linux server to host my WordPress site, it worked fine the 1st day but after that the mysql service stops and I have to start it from the command line. 
My mysql.log shows the bellow but still not sure what I should do to avoid this as I am new to linux servers.

Can anyone help. Thanks

```
Version: '5.5.52'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 
161125 17:52:42 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
161126 07:44:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
161126  7:44:16 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52) starting as process 7313 ...
161126  7:44:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
161126  7:44:16 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 205462348
161126  7:44:16  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 205602125
161126  7:44:16  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
161126  7:44:16  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
161126  7:44:17 InnoDB: 5.5.52 started; log sequence number 205602125
161126  7:44:17 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
161126  7:44:17 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
161126  7:44:17 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
161126  7:44:17 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
161126  7:44:17 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.52'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: This, admittedly, *looks like* MySQL crashing, but I don't think that's really the root problem -- it looks like a symptom.  Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31196872/1695906) and the other answers mentioned within, and note the parallels to your scenario.  When MySQL actually crashes, `mysqld_safe Number of processes running now` line will almost always be preceeded by a crash dump and a stack trace (or a message telling you that if there is no stack trace then something has gone terribly wrong).

Comment: What instance size are you using? Do you see anything related to mysql in the messages log file?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I will monitor it a bit more and see if the issue still occurs, the last 2 days it seems ok.

Comment: Problem still occurs, is their a chance that the httpd is shutting it down to save memory?

Comment: Im using a t2,micro instance